# jQuery Masonry doesn't work immediately after appending container

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I am appending a div with elements in it to the DOM and want to use masonry to arrange these inner elements. Unless I initialize masonry in a setTimeout callback, however, masonry breaks.

```
// I have a `#media` div in my html
var outerDiv = $('<div>').attr('style', 'width: 720px;');
this.$('#media').append(div);

// I create lots of boxes in a boxes div
var boxes = $('<div>').append(
  $('<div>').attr('style', 'width: 160px; height: 180px; margin: 10px 0px; ' +
      'background-color: red; float: left;').addClass('item'),
  $('<div>').attr('style', 'width: 340px; height: 120px; margin: 10px 0px; ' +
      'background-color: red; float: left;').addClass('item'),
  $('<div>').attr('style', 'width: 160px; height: 120px; margin: 10px 0px; ' +
      'background-color: red; float: left;').addClass('item'),
  $('<div>').attr('style', 'width: 160px; height: 180px; margin: 10px 0px; ' +
      'background-color: red; float: left;').addClass('item'),
  $('<div>').attr('style', 'width: 340px; height: 100px; margin: 10px 0px; ' +
      'background-color: red; float: left;').addClass('item'),
  $('<div>').attr('style', 'width: 340px; height: 160px; margin: 10px 0px; ' +
      'background-color: red; float: left;').addClass('item'),
  $('<div>').attr('style', 'width: 160px; height: 180px; margin: 10px 0px; ' +
      'background-color: red; float: left;').addClass('item'),
  $('<div>').attr('style', 'width: 160px; height: 120px; margin: 10px 0px; ' +
      'background-color: red; float: left;').addClass('item')
);

outerDiv.append(boxes);

// without the setTimeout wrapper, this breaks (in Chrome, everything clusters
// in the top left; in Firefox, everything lines up in a column on the left)
setTimeout(function() {
  boxes.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: 180,
    isResizable: true,
  });
});
```

Thoughts?

Comment: If you read the masonry docs then you can find the appended method. http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/methods.html

Comment: The appended method is useful for when you have a container with boxes inside that are already masonried, then you append additional elements inside. This is not the issue here: the bug is showing up during initial masonry setup.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked "Unloaded media and overlapping" in the Masonry documentation? See also [this discussion](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/58) and hints from the developer. Your issue is also showing without Ajax loading and other loaders, it is often that the content does not arrive in time because it is very data-heavy.

Masonry needs the content in each div (images, text or video) to work out all div dimensions - before the layout can be calculated first time. If you're loading images with imagesloaded or if your images are very large, or similar, Masonry has no dimensions (from the content) to work from and will show this typical "error". That's why your

```
setTimeout(function() {
  boxes.masonry({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  columnWidth: 180,
  isResizable: true,
});
```

works in this case, because enough time passes for the content to load/append/appear/be constructed.